# Typescript "Control Flow Analysis for Dependent Parameters"

Tags: typescript

As I understand it this should work via Typescript's "[Control Flow Analysis for Dependent Parameters](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#control-flow-analysis-for-dependent-parameters)"

```js
class Model {
  name: string
  age: number
}

function findUnique(id: string, parent?: boolean) {
  return {name: 'foo', age: 33}
}

function findMany(skip: number, take: number){
  return [{name: 'foo', age: 33}, {name: 'bar', age: 66}]
}

class Foo {
  read(page: number, psize: number): Model[] | null
  read(id: string, include: {parent?: boolean} | undefined): Model | null
  read(...args: [number, number] | [string, {parent?: boolean} | undefined]): Model | Model[] | null {
    if(typeof args[0] === 'string') {
      const [id, include] = args // as [string, {parent?: boolean} | undefined]
      return findUnique(id, include?.parent)
    }
    const [page, psize] = args // as [number, number]
    return findMany(page * psize, psize)
  }
}
```

Typescript version = 4.9.4

Inside the `if` statement Typescript still reports: `(parameter) args: [number, number] | [string, {parent?: boolean} | undefined]` - I would have thought it would of reported it to be `[string, {parent?: boolean} | undefined]`

Wondering what could be wrong here?

Comment: Neither `string` nor `number` are seen as discriminant types.  Going to bed now but if nobody answers before I wake up I’ll write one

Comment: Oh, so it's on the value not the type of the parameter that Typescript discriminates on?
If so, what mechanism should I use (besides defining two different methods)?

Comment: No, it *is* on the type, and the type is `string` or `number`, neither of which are seen as discriminant types (as opposed to string or number *literal* types like `"foo"` or `"bar"`). Before I write up an answer it would be helpful if you could [edit] the code to be a self-contained [mre] without undeclared types or values.  Anything like `db` or `Model` should be either defined, or even better, replaced with native values/types.

Comment: code has been edited.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wXzoOm) meet your needs?  Since TS doesn't automatically narrow non-discriminated-union objects, the workaround would be to write a custom type guard function to do it for you.  If that fully addresses your question I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: that works! still good to have the overloaded methods in order to narrow the return type.

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer (and yeah I somehow missed that the return types for the call signatures were different)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the type

```
[number, number] | [string, {parent?: boolean} | undefined]
```

is not considered a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) in TypeScript.  In order for a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) to be considered a discriminated union, it has to have a *discriminant* property containing some [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types).  But the property at key `0` is either `string` or `number`, neither of which is a literal type.  So checking `typeof args[0] === 'string'` unfortunately has no narrowing effect on `args`.

This is considered a desgin limitation according to [microsoft/TypeScript#30506](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30506), so you'll need to work around it.

---

If you don't want to significantly refactor your code so that the arguments are seen as a discriminated union (e.g., add a literal type argument like `"page" or` "id"`to distinguish), you can get similar narrowing behavior by replacing the`typeof args[0] === 'string'` check with a call to a [custom type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates). Custom type guard functions give more control over how narrowing happens.

Here's one way to do it:

```
function hasStringProp<T extends object, K extends PropertyKey>(
    obj: T, k: K): obj is Extract<T, Record<K, string>> {
    return (typeof (obj as any)[k] === "string");
}
```

So `hasStringProb(obj, k)` will check if `obj[k]` is of type `string`, and if so, the compiler will know to filter the union type of `obj` to include just those members with a `string` property at key `k`, by using [the `Extract<T, U>` union-filtering utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union).

Then the `read()` implementation becomes:

```
class Foo {
    read(page: number, psize: number): Model[] | null
    read(id: string, include: { parent?: boolean } | undefined): Model | null
    read(...args: [number, number] | 
      [string, { parent?: boolean }?]): Model | Model[] | null {
        if (hasStringProp(args, 0)) {
            const [id, include] = args
            return findUnique(id, include?.parent)
        }
        const [page, psize] = args
        return findMany(page * psize, psize)
    }
}
```

and everything works.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyD2ATApiaBvAUNH0B2YAtsgFzQQAuATgJZ4Dm0AvNAESvQD0n0AnvAFdyAC0EhE0OjQo0wIGgC9k0AA5V4KiNlxh6pfAMIAjZFWbQAjFx6JpFeJgC+mTADMBeYDPh5oruogAqng0AI4CyAAUNIhklLQMADSqYFTIeBQA-GRG8PAgyGB4AJQY2jhpFAJUvuj4RPoA5K55jcm6+gDMndDOzm4eXjQ+fgGwRbyREADWNCpkeIYmVMkUYNP6i8ampVi40JXVvgDadQTEZM2t7Xpk3b3JZw2XRqlt0B1kAGxfvQC6Thc3GgFGENBgyEIAnAFGQMFBygIVHUAHc6IwTMIwAA3YZmfhCFFFWGIAaeby+LEQADK1HRAAV1CoADwAFWgyAAHrC8IgYPAjAArZBeZIAaQ53PSfOgjI0pgovDFyF4AD5IuVoALBWRWclpmQxcUyNrJDAAKLcqhgLxs5IAJRF8CoiGZYuS8XRqtVZX2hxq0EiipUyHgrkDpsgHzwvGKx2mf2YTBYrE9DFYxQA3IDMKBIDAAGJ5X24NJgRCRFSfAzbFaqCCKTZLHZkBAoEDHRMAHwMIBAmrLFZicTpSUknhAAhQZDqVbSGWy0Fy+UKvkc0B7HhQ-jwyEQxrgSFQG97-b9hQrADpr6l6BAyMctstkk-TN3oMc0-RHil51kcnkBRFL0mR-AebbHj2EEdu+ix9iW+w4DQ4aRFStIJPQcoqJEt4QMkAAMxS7JqiG4MAPiUB+MTJHQoBTsgiYsLhJGkQcyBVAGO5BCE4RRNR450SgmSXnO6QUMULE4M4rHQOReCUccVZ6MkmiNoxHxUHeklsRxvhceMMaVh00AAFT1o2KkNkoEn7H0mBAA)